# How do I reload the page after all ajax calls complete?

Tags: javascript, jquery

The first time a user is visiting my website, I am pulling a lot of information from various sources using a couple of ajax calls. How do I reload the page once the ajax calls are done?

```
if(userVisit != 1) {
  // First time visitor
  populateData();
}

function populateData() {
  $.ajax({
            url: "server.php",
            data: "action=prepare&myid=" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.error) { 
                    return;
                }
                _id = response[json].id;
                getInformation(_id);
            }
  });
}

function getInformation(id) {
  $.ajax({
            url: "REMOTESERVICE",
            data: "action=get&id=" + id,
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(json) {
                if(json.error) { 
                    return;
                }

                $.ajax({
                       url: "server.php",
                       data: "action=update&myid=" + id + '&data=' + json.data.toString(),
                       dataType: "json",
                       success: function(json) {
                                if(json.error) { 
                                    return;
                                }
                      }
                });
            }
  });
}
```

So what the code does is, it gets a list of predefined identifiers for a new user (`populateData` function) and uses them to get more information from a thirdparty service (`getInformation` function). This `getInformation` function queries a third party server and once the server returns some data, it sends that data to my server through another ajax call. Now what I need is a way to figure out when all the ajax calls have been completed so that I can reload the page. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

In your `getInformation()` call you can call [`location.reload()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.location) in your [`success`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) callback, like this:

```
success: function(json) {
  if(!json.error) location.reload(true);
}
```

To wait until any *further* ajax calls complete, you can use the [`ajaxStop` event](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/), like this:

```
success: function(json) {
  if(json.error) return;
  //fire off other ajax calls
  $(document).ajaxStop(function() { location.reload(true); });
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But what if some ajax calls to my server inside the `success` callback in the `getInformation` function are still pending? Wouldn't this just refresh the page without considering that? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Legend - Yes, if you want to delay until they're all done, just do `$(document).ajaxStop(function() { location.reload(true); });` and it'll execute when all those requests complete.

Comment: That makes total sense but for some reason, when I insert this call, the page keep refreshing all the time.

Comment: @Legend - Are you running these functions even after the user data has been loaded?  If that's the case it'll keep reloading like that.

Comment: You are right. I fixed it. Thanks a lot. Works perfectly... Just one thing though... It works in Chrome but in Firefox, it keeps restarting like before...

Comment: @NickCraver  add it out of all ajax requests, after it and works super fine. Thanks bro.

Answer (score 1):

.ajaxStop() works fine to me, page is reloaded after all ajax calls.

You can use as the following example :

```
$( document ).ajaxStop(function() {
  window.location = window.location;
});
```

How it's works?
A: Whenever an Ajax request completes, jQuery checks whether there are any other outstanding Ajax requests. If none remain, jQuery triggers the ajaxStop event.

Hope help y'all, furthermore information, I'm sharing the link of the documentation following.

source: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxstop/

Answer (score 0):

You could just redirect to the same page in the server.php file where the function is defined using a header('Location: html-page');

Answer (score -2):

```
//document.location.reload(true);
window.location = window.location;
```

- See more at: http://www.dotnetfunda.com/forums/show/17887/issue-in-ie-11-when-i-try-to-refresh-my-parent-page-from-the-popupwind#sthash.gZEB8QV0.dpuf

Comment: I can kinda see what you're getting at but you should try to reiterate what your link demonstrates. I'm guessing you mean to say document.location.reload(true) doesn't work as expected on pages with POST data?